# How to ensure timely memory release in Python?

Tags: python

in my current project, there's a requirement for memory constraints. There's a step in my project where I release a portion of content before loading new content. Based on my debugging with memory_profiler in Python, it seems that memory release doesn't work as I designed. I'd like to know how to address this issue.

If I only perform memory checks on the run function, my memory usage remains around 5GB. However, if I monitor memory usage in the move_tensor function and the loading_tensor function, I find that in the move function, memory isn't being released (there should theoretically be 3GB of content released), while in the load function, memory reaches 8GB (an additional 3GB of content is loaded into memory).

```
def move_tensor():
    self.cacheData[0] = self.cacheData[0][NUM:] 
    self.cacheData[1] = self.cacheData[1][NUM:]

def loading_tensor():
    self.cacheData[0] = torch.cat([self.cacheData[0],tmp_data])
    self.cacheData[1] = torch.cat([self.cacheData[1],tmp_data])

def run():
    move_tensor()
    loading_tensor()
```

Comment: Please provide [a Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code is incomplete and likely lacks the information needed to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import gc


# when you do not need some variable or object 
gc.collect()
# if you use torch and cuda, use follow together with gc.collect()
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```